# Pentaho dependency is not working on Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, pentaho

I am trying to include Pentaho dependency in my spring boot application but it is now working please anyone can help me how can I make it work?

When I am tying to fetch or build the project it is giving me error as below:

```
Could not find artifact pentaho-reporting-engine:pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core:pom:7.0.0.6-95 in spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone)
```

here is my below pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Pentaho dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.6-95</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-database-model</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.6-95</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.6-95</version>

    </dependency>
    
    ........ few more libraries are their of pentaho

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni</url>

    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I am using spring-boot 2.6.8 and maven 3.

Please help if anyone know how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you try to manually search pentaho at https://repo.spring.io/? or you can using maven repository for pentaho.

Comment: Remove the spring.io repositories because access is not allowed...furthermore the dependency pentaho-reporting-engine does not exist in central repository... you need to find a repo where it's available...

Comment: but for pentaho I have added different repository. It is working spring-boot 2.2.5 but not here.

Comment: I resolved it in pentaho repository url "/" was missing in the end: "https://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/" and now it is working fine. Thank you all :)